# Rotate the UIImage from CGPDFPage

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics

After using the method from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-render-a-pdf-to-an-image

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {

    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in

        UIColor.white.set()

        ctx.fill(pageRect)
        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}
```

I would like to rotate the output image directly by using

```
 ctx.rotate(by: 90/180*CGFloat.pi)
```

But it is not working. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, the resulting image should have as width the height of the PDF and the height of the image should be the width of the PDF, because we want to rotate the output:

[image: Intended rotated output]

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {

    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)

    let imageSize = CGSize(width: pageRect.height, height: pageRect.width)
    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()

        ctx.fill(imageRect)
        ctx.cgContext.rotate(by:CGFloat.pi / 2)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}
```

This code gives then the following result (background of super view is greenish to better distinguish the resulting image with the white background):

[image: Rotated PDF as image]

Most likely you don't want to use the exact same size values as the PDF. Instead you may want to multiply the image resolution with a factor. Then the code would look like this:

```
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) -> UIImage? {

    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let factor: CGFloat = 3.0
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: pageRect.height * factor, height: pageRect.width * factor)
    let imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()

        ctx.fill(imageRect)
        ctx.cgContext.rotate(by:CGFloat.pi / 2)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: factor, y: -factor)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}
```